# Strange reputation behaviour 10/11 July 2010

Tags: support, reputation

I have done a search for this - if it's still a dup my apologies.

Yesterday evening (GMT+1 this is, I'm in the UK) I went from 2833 rep to 3003 after receiving lots of upvotes on questions and answers.

I thought this was a little suspicious given the number of votes.

At the time, the only question I was directly dealing with was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194678/expressiontdelegate-compile-in-medium-trust-environment/3195190#3195190) and, at the time my answer was accepted, it had one upvote.  Coming back today I now find my rep has dropped to 2818, the answer is still accepted, but has now got no votes.

All the other +reps have also disappeared.

So it would seem that all votes were reversed at some point overnight and now I've taken a step back in rep!

Okay, it's only 20-30 points; but it is a bloody pain!

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a 'fan' that went through all of your answers and up-voted some of them in a short period of time. I'm sure there was no malice involved, however the behavior matches the pattern of someone using another account to award themselves reputation. Its impossible to progmatically determine 'intent' in these kinds of cases.

The same (but reverse) thing would have happened if someone down-voted all of your answers, your reputation would have been restored.

The algorithm runs once per day, I believe in the late evening hours (your time).

Comment: interesting - I think it's possible that the guy I helped out might have been that fan.  ah well - c'est la vie!

Comment: Correct; in addition, this triggers a reputation recalc after the suspicious votes have been removed. That's likely why the reputation ended up lower than it was before.